# How can I contact the PUBLISHER of a Meteor package?

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

atmosphere.js's UI directs one to the github project for any published project.  But the project stakeholders are often unrelated to the person/org who published it on atmosphere (using a meteor account), and often don't even have any idea who it is.

When the github project is updated, often the publisher is slow at updating the meteor package - or may have moved on and will never do it.  AFAICT, there's no way to get any contact info for the publisher.

I've run into this problem twice now.  Am I missing something?

I'm looking for general advice, but the specific package I'm trying to research is `jonatan:angular-google-places-autocomplete`.  'jonatan' has packaged and published three package wrappers, and AFAICT (unreliable!) they're not a contributor to any of them.  I'm not being critical - I'm just saying that there's no way to figure out who it is.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - care to share any tips?

Comment: These packages by jonatan are unusual in the sense that they do not point to the git repo of the package itself (as they should). Usually the github link will bring you to the git repo of the package and there you can contact the maintainer (filing issues and such).

Comment: @ChristianFritz They may not be done correctly, but in my experience this isn't unusual at all - especially when you exclude the cases where a "base" project member is also maintaining the meteor package.  That's what prompted me to write!